# How to make some products available only for premium users

Tags: sylius

In my Sylius shop, I would like to make some products available only for my website premium users.

I managed to set up a promotion rule for premium users, according to the documentation : [How to add a custom promotion rule?](http://docs.sylius.org/en/latest/cookbook/custom-promotion-rule.html)

My problem is that I can't figure out how to create a promotion action, making selected products available only to premium users. And these products need also to be seen by standard customers.

Is a promotion action a good way to achieve this purpose ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if promotions are the best you can use in this feature. There is no discount/profit for the customer, it's just a limitation of product for specific customer group. I would solve this with two simple steps:

1. Add *$premium* flag on `Product` entity.
2. Implement a listener (or even better - a validator) that would check the currently logged in customer groups and if there is no **premium**, then break adding product to cart and display proper message.

Of course, you could create a promotion action that would remove products from cart that customer can't buy, but let's be honest, it'd be ridiculous ;)

Let me know if it's clear or you need any more help with that!

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I agree with you, it would be ridiculous to remove products form cart. As for now, I already have a premium flag on Product entity and if modified the product template to disable the "add to cart" button. But the logic of this is only on the frontend side. I will have a look at the validator in order to get a server side check.